# How can I process only files that have changed?

Tags: ant

At the moment I'm doing this:

```
<delete dir="${RSA.dir}/file1" />
<copy todir="${RSA.dir}/file1" >
    <fileset dir="${CLEARCASE.dir}/file1" />            
</copy>
```

and repeating the same thing for other files - but it takes a long time.

I only want to delete and copy files that have been updated, with their modified date in clearcase later than that in RSA.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

Look into the [sync](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sync.html) task.

If you want to do it based on file contents, and ignore the timestamp, I think this macro will do that:

```
<macrodef name="mirror" description="Copy files only if different; remove files that do not exist in dir. This works similiar to robocopy /MIR." >
    <attribute name="dir"/>
    <attribute name="todir"/>
    <sequential>
        <copy overwrite="true" todir="@{todir}">
            <fileset dir="@{dir}">
                <different targetdir="${todir}"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <delete includeemptydirs="true">
            <fileset dir="@todir}">
                <present targetdir="${dir}" present="srconly"/>
            </fileset>                
        </delete>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a [selector](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html) on a FileSet.  Something like this:

```
<fileset dir="${your.working.dir}/src/main" includes="**/*.java">
    <different targetdir="${clean.clearcase.checkout}/src/main"
        ignoreFileTimes="false"
        ignoreContents="true" />
</fileset>
```

That compares your working dir to a clean checkout you have elsewhere, and returns the files whose last modified times have changed.  You can use the fileset as the argument for a `<delete>` or a `<copy>`.